# Sudden error with Xcode 14 RC: Not entitled to listen to push notifications. Please add the 'aps-connection-initiate' entitlement

Tags: cloudkit, xcode14

I just downloaded the Xcode 14 release candidate and I started getting the following crashing error on startup (didn't try the other betas). I made no changes in the codebase. CloudKit was working fine before:

```
[CK] BUG IN CLIENT OF CLOUDKIT: Not entitled to listen to push notifications. Please add the 'aps-connection-initiate' entitlement.
```

Under Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles in the Developer portal, I've verified that push notifications are enabled.

To fix, I tried removing and re-adding the push-notifications entitlement.

[image]

I verified that the APS Environment value is in the entitlements .plist.[image]

I switched off automatic signing and then turned it back on again. I cleaned the build and deleted derived data. I also tried switching back to Xcode 13.4.1 and everything started working again - unfortunately, not a solution.

The error occurs right as container.loadPersistentStores is called.

```
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer = {
        /*
         The persistent container for the application. This implementation
         creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
         application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
         error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
         */

        let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "not_real_name")
        
        guard let description = container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first else {
            fatalError("No descriptions found (AppDelegate.persistentContainer)")
        }
        
        description.setOption(true as NSObject, forKey: NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationPostOptionKey)
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: {
            (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
```

Is this just an Xcode beta bug (in the release candidate)? Is there a way to work around it?

Comment: As I said, I tried that.

Comment: Have the same problem in Xcode Version 14.0.1 (14A400). Did you find a solution?

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution for this ?

Answer (score 4):

I also just ran into this error today, on the Xcode 14.0 RC. It was on a basically brand new project so I figured it must be something odd with the new version.

To fix, I just did what the error said:

```
    <key>aps-connection-initiate</key>
    <true/>
```

Added that to the app's Info.plist, then it ran again just fine. Also SwiftUI previews started working again.

Comment: That's what I tried and it's not working.

Comment: For me, it was adding this entitlement to the Entitlements File not the InfoPlist.

Comment: I am getting this problem while running unit tests. I added this key to the App info.plist + Entitlements and the Test info.plist but still get the error. My CoreData stack is in its own SPM package, is that going to make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this in simulator. Go to `Device -> Erase all content ad settings..` And reinstall the app.

Answer (score 0):

open .entitlements file

and then add "aps-connection-initiate" key and set the value to true

That worked for me

Comment: I found that adding this key to entitlements broke automatic signing